# Why does Q-value become negative during training of DQN, while the agent learns to play?

Tags: deep-rl, dqn, gym

I have implemented a simple version of the DQN algorithm for `CartPole-v0`. The algorithm works fine, in the sense that achieves the highest possible scores. The below diagram shows the cumulative reward versus training episode.
[image: reward plot]

The scary part is when I tried to plot the q values during training. For this purpose, 1000 random states were generated and stored. After each training episode, I fed these states to the Q-network and computed the Q-value for all actions. Then for each state, the max Q-value was computed. Finally, these max Q-values were averaged to yield a single number. The following plot shows this quantity during training.
[image]

As you can see, there is a slight increase in average-max-q in the beginning and it is followed by a sharp decrease. My question is, **how can this value be negative?** Since I know all rewards received by the agent are positive, and expected cumulative reward of a state can not be negative.

## Edit

I added the code for clarity:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import torch as th
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import gym
import random
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

from test_avg_q import TestEnv


class ReplayBuffer():
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=maxlen)

    def add(self, experience):
        self.buffer.append(experience)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        sample_size = min(len(self.buffer), batch_size)
        samples = random.choices(self.buffer, k=sample_size)
        return map(list, zip(*samples))


class QNetwork():
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_size):
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.q_net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(state_dim, 100),
                                   nn.ReLU(),
                                   nn.Linear(100, action_size))
        self.optimizer = th.optim.Adam(self.q_net.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    def update_model(self, state, action, q_target):
        action = th.Tensor(action).to(th.int64)
        action_one_hot = F.one_hot(action, num_classes=self.action_size)
        q = self.q_net(th.Tensor(state))
        q_a = th.sum(q * action_one_hot, dim=1)
        loss = nn.MSELoss()(q_a, q_target)
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()


class DQNAgent():
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.state_dim = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.action_size = env.action_space.n
        self.q_network = QNetwork(self.state_dim, self.action_size)
        self.replay_buffer = ReplayBuffer(maxlen=1_000_000)
        self.gamma = 0.97
        self.eps = 1.0

    def get_action(self, state):
        with th.no_grad():
            q_state = self.q_network.q_net(th.Tensor(state).unsqueeze(0))
            action_greedy = th.argmax(q_state).item()
        action_random = np.random.randint(self.action_size)
        action = action_random if random.random() < self.eps else action_greedy
        return action

    def train(self, state, action, next_state, reward, done):
        self.replay_buffer.add((state, action, next_state, reward, done))
        states, actions, next_states, rewards, dones = self.replay_buffer.sample(50)
        with th.no_grad():
            q_next_states = self.q_network.q_net(th.Tensor(next_states))
            q_next_states[dones] = th.zeros(self.action_size)
            q_targets = th.Tensor(rewards) + self.gamma * th.max(q_next_states, dim=1)[0]
        self.q_network.update_model(states, actions, q_targets)

        if done: self.eps = max(0.1, 0.99 * self.eps)


env_name = "CartPole-v0"
env = gym.make(env_name)

agent = DQNAgent(env)
num_episodes = 400
testEnv = TestEnv()
avg_qs = []
rewards = []
render = False

for ep in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    total_reward = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        action = agent.get_action(state)
        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        agent.train(state, action, next_state, reward, done)
        total_reward += reward
        state = next_state
        if render and ep > 80:
            env.render()

    avg_qs.append(testEnv.run(agent.q_network.q_net))
    rewards.append(total_reward)
    print("Episode: {}, total_reward: {:.2f}".format(ep, total_reward))

plt.plot(avg_qs)
plt.show()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(rewards)
plt.show()
```

here is the code for class `TestEnv`:

```
import torch as th
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


class TestEnv:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataloader = DataLoader(TestDataset(), batch_size=100, num_workers=10)

    def run(self, model):
        out_list = []
        model.eval()
        with th.no_grad():
            for batch in self.dataloader:
                out = model(batch)
                out_list.append(out)
            qs = th.cat(out_list, dim=0)
            maxq = th.max(qs, dim=1)[0]
            result = th.mean(maxq)
        return result.item()



class TestDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = th.load('test_states.pt')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.db)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.db[idx]
```

Comment: Maybe link your implementation. I would suspect a bug in your code somewhere, as you point out accurate Q values for real states should at least be positive. I don't think it is possible to predict where the bug is from the graphs.

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks, I added the code.

Comment: for me, it would be possible that your 1000 random states are not a good representation of the gigantic state space of the problem, most states in the problem yield very bad outcome, only a part of them can be considered of interest (e.g. the ones where the pole is more of less straight).
if your 1000 all lead to certain fail, the max expected reward for those states can only go down, because you never want to reach them, nor their child.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem (mean q-value increases and then decreases). Did you figure this out?

Comment: Look up the deadly triad. There is a lot of literature devoted to the overestimation of Q values.